# Save join table item without foreign key

Tags: ruby-on-rails, many-to-many, join

I have two models, Users and Clubs.  A user can create a club and then add member to the club. To accomplish such, I have a join table called Membership, as such:

```
class Membership < ActiveRecord::Base

  attr_accessible :member_id, :club_id, :name, :email

  belongs_to :club
  belongs_to :member, class_name: "User"

  validates :club_id, presence: true

end
```

To create a membership, I have a form that asks for the name and email of a club member, and also passes the :club_id through a hidden field.

```
<%= form_for(@club.memberships.create(:club_id => @club.id)) do |f| %>
  <%= f.hidden_field :club_id %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.text_field :name, placeholder: "Name" %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.text_field :email, placeholder: "Email" %>
  </div>
  <div class="action">
    <%= f.submit "Add", class: "btn" %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

The :email is sent to the controller to look up that user's ID and a membership is created with the :club_id and :member_id, and the User's name linking to their profile is placed on the Club's page.  Everything works fine if the email address is already associated with a User.

Controller:

```
def create
  @club = Club.find(params[:membership][:club_id])
  unless User.find_by_email(params[:membership][:email]).id.nil?
    params[:membership][:member_id] = User.find_by_email(params[:membership][:email]).id
    @club.memberships.create(params[:membership])
    flash[:success] = "Club member successfully added"
    redirect_to :back
  else
    @club.memberships.create(params[:membership])     ##<-- This is where I need help
    redirect_to :back
  end
end
```

If there is no user associated with that email, however, the lookup returns nil, as expected.  I am wondering how I can get this membership to save with just the name and no :member_id.  I'd like it to still be able to display that Club member's name on the Club page, but with no link to their profile obviously.  Then the email could be used to send them a message indicating that someone has indicated that they are a member of a Club on my site, but primarily I just want to have their name still displayed on that Club's page.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just create a user for a new email ? Then all nil and displaying stuff could be solved. The easiest way to keep current structure.